# where could I find the source function definition?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I downloaded the source code of datagrid on this website. http://www.datatables.net/. But **I cannot find the source code** for dataTables() in the JS file, **jquery.dataTables.js,**  which draws the actual table on my webpage.

In my html file, I call the dataTable via,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.js, the `DataTable` function, `var DataTable = function( oInit )`, near the beginning of the file.

Comment: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L12118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js

<kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> `$.fn.dataTable`

Which then locates:

```
// jQuery aliases
$.fn.DataTable = DataTable;
$.fn.dataTable = DataTable;
$.fn.dataTableSettings = DataTable.settings;
$.fn.dataTableExt = DataTable.ext;
```

So, now we find `DataTable`:

```
var DataTable = function( oInit )
{
```

Which is right at the top.

---

The `DataTables`library is an object library of its own; all they do is create jQuery extensions that just point to the custom object using `$.fn` (which is `jQuery.prototype`). so basically, without losing the original `DataTable` reference, you now have:

```
/* $.fn       */./*alias*/ = /*Datatable var */
jQuery.prototype.dataTable = function( oInit ){
  // ...
}
```